# Merging multiple objects a array of Objects obtained from server in ANGULAR 4?

Tags: angular, observable

I am getting multiple objects from server and i am returning that i want to store them as Array of objects in angular 4 .

service :

```
  search(term: string): Observable<Array<Object>> {
       let apiURL =`${this.apiRoot}?search=${term}`;
        return this.http.get(apiURL)
          .map(res => {
        return res.json().results.map(items => {
          items.name,
          items.population
        });
         });
      }
   }
```

Component :

```
private results : [Object];
this.searchField = new FormControl();
  this.searchField.valueChanges
       .debounceTime(400)
       .distinctUntilChanged()
       .switchMap(term => this.myservice.search(term))
       .subscribe(value => console.log(value) );

}  
}
```

I am not getting Array of Objects ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
search(term: string): Observable<Array<Object>> {
    let apiURL =`${this.apiRoot}?search=${term}`;

    return this.http.get(apiURL)
        .map(res => res.json().results )
        .flatMap( results => Observable.from(results) )
        //single values remap is happening below
        .map( result => {
            name: result.name,
            population : result.population
        })
        .toArray();
}
```

The flatmap is used to transform a value ( array ) into an observable that emits single values. The map after the flatMap is used to reshape the items. The final toArray bundle up all the emitted values. This approach may be more verbose than direct mapping inside the first map call, but it is cleaner and can be easily changed, and it is not nested

Answer (score 0):

You can use [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) to concatenate array together. If these are arrays of objects, you will essentially merge the arrays into one big array. For instance, this...

```
[].concat([{name:'foo'}], [{name:'bar'}], [{name:'baz'}])
```

...will evaluate to a single array of 3 objects:

```
[{name:'foo'}, {name:'bar'}, {name:'baz'}]
```

Even if your objects are not already in an array, you will get the same result doing this:

```
[].concat({name:'foo'}, {name:'bar'}, {name:'baz'})
```

So in your code, you should be able to do something like this, given that  `items.name` and `items.population` are both objects:

```
search(term: string): Observable<Array<Object>> {
    let apiURL =`${this.apiRoot}?search=${term}`;

    return this.http.get(apiURL)
        .map(res => {
            return res.json().results.map(items => {
                return [].concat(items.name, items.population);
            });
        });
}
```

EDIT: `[].concat(...)` returns an array, and it is being returned in `map` which also returns an array, so that is why you get getting an array or arrays. In order to get an array of objects, do the following:

```
search(term: string): Observable<Array<Object>> {
    let apiURL =`${this.apiRoot}?search=${term}`;

    return this.http.get(apiURL)
        .map(res => {
            return res.json().results.map(items => {
                return {name: items.name, population: items.population};
            });
        });
}
```

Now you will get an array of objects, like so:

```
[{name: ..., population: ...}, {...}]
```

Comment: Does the map of results return an array of the whole starting one? It seems like it should return nothing, unless you have a reference to the reducing array. The map fn in an array does return a new array reference

Comment: The `results.map` is returning a new array of arrays. If you want one single array, you can use `reduce` to reduce the multiple arrays into one.

Comment: @Lansana i am getting array of array and i want array of objects . Can you please why i am getting this

Comment: @TarikSahni Updated answer.